# << operator in C++?

Tags: c++, operators, bit

I am new to C++, what's the exact meaning for the `<<` in statement below, Thanks.

```
if (Val & (0x0001 << 0))
{}
else
{}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a shift-left operation.  If you have:

```
a << b
```

where `a` and `b` are integral types (char, short, long, etc.), then the bits in `a` are shifted left `b` places with zeroes filling in on the right.  In other words, `a` is multiplied by `2^b`.

Example:

```
12 << 3

12 (decimal) = 00001100 (binary)
```

shift left 3 places:

```
00001100 becomes 01100000
```

which is 96 (which is `12 * 8` or `12 * 2^3`)

Comment: Corollary: `<< 0` has no effect whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

It means shift 0x0001 number 0 bits to the left. In that specific case, it does nothing.

For example, if it was `(0x0001 << 4)`, 0x0001 would become 0x0010. Each position shifted left is like multiplying the number by 2.

Comment: So, `Val & (0x0001 << 1)` means shift bit1 to left and & operate with Val?

Comment: No, it means shift 0x0001 one bit left, so it becomes 0x0002.

Comment: @Nano: Yep, same as `Val & 2`.

Comment: @Nano: it shifts *all* the bits to the left by that many places

Answer (score 0):

That is a [bit shift operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_shift#Bit_shifts).

But when integers aren't involved, beware of an underlying [overloaded operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1z2f6c2k%28VS.80%29.aspx).