# What does << means in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am looking at some code in javascript

```
var numCombos = 1<<numActive;
```

numActive = 8 returns numCombos = 256

what does << means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means bitwise left shift. Same as it means in most other programming languages.

Some console test:

```
>a = 2
2
>a << 1 
4
>a << 3
16
```

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators

Comment: @edelweiss if you had googled then it would have been much more faster :P

Answer (score 4):

It's the bitwise left operator. In `a << b`, it shifts `a` in binary representation `b` (< 32) bits to the left, shifting in zeros from the right.

Some examples:

```js
a = 1       // 00000001 in binary
b = a << 1  // equals to 2, 00000010 in binary
c = a << 2  // equals to 4, 00000100 in binary

document.write('a << 1 = ' + b + '<br />'
               + 'a << 2 = ' + c);
```

This operator is kind of standard, and a little search should lead you to a lot of already existing topics on StackOverflow like this one: [<< operator in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5798223/operator-in-c) or even this one: [What are bitwise shift (bit-shift) operators and how do they work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141525/absolute-beginners-guide-to-bit-shifting)